# multiple results in binary search when knowing first character of an word in java

Tags: java

Below you can see my code. It reads from `sort.txt` in which there are words from dictionary. It saves them to `arraylist3`. I need to do binary search from that list. For example:

If user inputs

```
A
```

The program does binary search of list3 in which there are words with length 3 and returns all possible solutions.

At the moment program only return position if full word is inputed:
So you need to input Aba and it return position but i need it to do as example below.

Example what program should do:

```
list3: [Aba, Aca, Ada, Baa, bbb, ddd, jjj]
```

User enters:

```
A
```

Program returns: Aba at position 0, Aca at position 1, Ada at postion 2.

That what I have so far. Please help kinda stuck here. Ignore the regular expresion comparison.

```
public class proba{


private final static int NOT_FOUND = -1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
String izbira;
int dolzina=0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String user_input;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();


try {

    File file = new File("sort.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String vrstica;

    while ((vrstica = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

        if (vrstica.length() == 3) {
            list3.add(vrstica);

        }
    }
    System.out.println(list3);
    do{
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter lenght of word:");
            if (in.hasNextInt()) {
                dolzina = in.nextInt();
            } else if (in.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.printf("Wrong entry!%n ",
                        in.nextLine());
            } 
        } while (dolzina <= 0);

    Collections.sort(list3);

    System.out.println("Enter the first character of a word you are searching:");
    user_input = input.nextLine();
    //user_input = user_input.replace("*", ".");

    System.out.println("Sorted list: [length: " + list3.size() + "]");
    System.out.println(list3);


    if (dolzina == 3) {

            int index = binarySearch(list3, user_input);
            System.out.println("Found" + user_input +" at " + index);

    }

    dolzina=-1;
    System.out.println("Ponovni vnos (da/ne):");
    Scanner inn= new Scanner (System.in);
    izbira = inn.next();

}while (izbira.equalsIgnoreCase("da"));
    bufferedReader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}
}


public static int binarySearch(List<String> integerList, String searchValue) {

int low = 0;
int high = integerList.size() - 1;
int mid = (low + high) / 2;

while (low <= high && !integerList.get(mid).equalsIgnoreCase(searchValue)) {

if (integerList.get(mid).compareTo(searchValue) < 0) {
    low = mid + 1;
} else {
    high = mid - 1;
}

mid = (low + high) / 2;

if (low > high) {
    mid = NOT_FOUND;
}

}
return mid;

 }

 }
```

Comment: So what's wrong? what do you expect it to do?

Comment: I see, you can use the binary search to return the position when the item should be if it was there. Search for binary sort for insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change this line:

`while (low <= high && !integerList.get(mid).equalsIgnoreCase(searchValue)) {`

to be

`while (low <= high && ! integerList.get( mid ).contains( searchValue ) ) {`

you're doing exact match where you want to be seeing if the string contains your character.

or, if you just want words that start with your substring

`while (low <= high && ! integerList.get( mid ).toUpperCase().startsWith( searchValue.toUpperCase() ) ) {`

cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot. Strugling here for last hour.